# Capacitors and MOSFET Integrated Circuit

Tags: transistors, capacitor, mosfet, rf, integrated-circuit

I have attached a basic Field Strength Meter circuit diagram that I drew. It functions as a basic RF detector. However, I want to try and design a circuit that could fit on a chip, therefore, using capacitors would be far too large. I was thinking that I could use transistors (Specifically MOSFETs) to replace these capactiors and make these MOSFETs behave like the capacitors given.

I was thinking if this is plausible and specifically how I would be able to implement this idea if its plausible.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really explicitly state a question, so I'll just comment on your design.

For the fixed capacitor of 10 nF: If it's too large of a capacitance, maybe you can try something like using the [Miller effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_effect). By placing a capacitor in parallel with a amplifier with negative gain, the effective capacitance can be much larger. The amplifier could be implemented with a common source amplifier using MOSFETs.

For the tuning capacitor something like a [varicap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicap) could work. Alternatively, going off of your idea of using a MOSFET, it's true that a MOSFET can be used as a capacitor. The integrated MOSFET is a 4 terminal device. By utilizing only the gate and body terminals we form a device known as a MOS capacitor. The drain and source are left unconnected. Since no potential is across the drain/source, electrons do not flow through the inversion channel. By controlling the gate voltage, we can control the depletion depth and thus the capacitance of the MOS device. Note that the capacitance of the MOS capacitor is highly non-linear. As such, you would have to appropriately bias the device.

---

Edit: More information on integrated MOS capacitors upon request.

Note that this with integrated MOSFETs as OP mentions he is doing IC design. This assumes some knowledge of the device physics of semiconductors. If anyone is looking for more information on device physics, I think that the [MIT OCW site](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-720j-integrated-microelectronic-devices-spring-2007/lecture-notes/) has decent material on the subject.

Assume we're deal with a standard n type MOSFET. That is we have some n silicon, with p wells for the drain and source, with a metal and oxide forming the gate. Note that the oxide is a dielectric. Now if we apply some voltage bias to the gate with respect to the body (bulk) of the device, charge will accumulate both on the gate and in the bulk. One side will be positively charged and the other negatively charged. This is capacitor. The gate and the bulk form the two terminals of the MOS capacitor.

Now, we still have those 2 p wells for the drain and source. Under standard operation of a MOSFET, we would bias those such that current flows from drain to source. We don't want current flow through the MOSFET, so you should short the drain and source together to prevent any current flow.

Some additional notes:

1) The capacitance will be small. I'd guess somewhere in the pF range, but I'd have to refresh my device physics memory. It scales with area though, so I suppose you could just chain a bunch.

2) Capacitance varies with the bias voltage. Below is a graph of the C-V curve of a MOSFET. The capacitance is on the y axis, voltage is on the x axis. As we can see, the capacitance is (a) not fixed with voltage (b) not particularly linearly related with voltage either.

[image: MOS cap C-V curve]

The best imagery for this is slide 7 in lecture 22 of the MIT OCW site. The reason the capacitance changes so wierdly with voltage is that depending on the bias, different effects become apparent in the semiconductor. For 1 range of operation which we call "depletion", the MOS structure works as I explained above, with charge piling up at the metal gate and in the MOS bulk. If the bias is too great, electrons will begin to pile up in the bulk right at the edge of the oxide. This reduces the effective charge between the two "plates" of the capacitor and reduces the capacitance.

If you are not familiar with this already, I would definitely recommend spending time working your way through a device physics class's material. Designing at the IC level is difficult without a good understanding of device physics.

In summary: You would need to short the drain and source, then bias the gate with respect to the bulk such that the capacitance would be in a region of the graph where it would vary appreciably with voltage.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. Thank you for the suggestion to the parallel capacitor being a bit too large; however, assuming I fixed that issue, could you more thoroughly explain how I would specifically use a MOSFET as a capacitor in this specific circuit? Do I simply replace each capacitor with a MOSFET and wire it in the way you described? I am a bit unfamiliar with MOSFETS, however, to bias these MOSFETs I would have to apply a specified voltage for these transistors to operate, correct?

Comment: Also how does controlling the gate voltage control the depletion depth and thus the capacitance? could you point me to the equations that show that relationship?

Comment: Added some more explanation and links upon request. Lecture 17, slide 10 of the MIT OCW site goes through the depletion width of a metal, semiconductor interface. It's similar to the space charge region in a PN junction if you are familiar with that.